# SSL Certificate Automation | Lets Encrypt

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, automation, dns, devops

I am working on a solution that provides a user to add a custom domain to their website/page the same way GitHub pages work (https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site).

Now, to achieve this functionilty we need to follow the following steps:

1. **Creating an SSL Certificate** (currently willing to go with Lets Encrypt, but open for other suggestions also)
2. Point A/CNAME to my backend server IP/DNS.

In this, when I am automating step 1 (Creating an SSL Certificate), the certbot command is asking for DNS verification (either via TXT records or email). I want to avoid this verification step, the same way services Like GitHub does i.e It ask the users only to add a CNAME for the pages, and SSL certificate is issued in the background (without any DNS verification).

Needed a solution by which I could automate the SSL creation, without waiting for DNS verification in the certbot command (sudo certbot --nginx -d [www.example.com](http://www.example.com))

Comment: I've done this when I have DNS in Route53 - it resolves very quickly.  Is that possible?

Comment: You can use [HTTP challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/)